# How to know the relative facing angles between two players?

Tags: unity, vector, angles

I want a grappling system similar to Tekken, in which different grapples animations  are performed depending on which side of the opponent the player performing the grapple is facing. For example, facing the opponent face to face would be different when he is facing the opponent's back or even facing the opponent from the side.

Overall I've seen three animations performed using the same buttons depending upon the side the player is facing the opponent. But I've no idea how to achieve this.

How can I tell if a player is facing the front, side or back of another player?

Comment: What are you stuck on?  Playing an animation?  Detecting which side of the opponent you're facing?

Comment: detecting the side of the opponent.

Comment: And for those of us who barely even knew that Tekken was a game, can you describe a bit more the situation?  2D?  3D?  If 3D, is it always on a ground plane, or can you fly or otherwise go at crazy angles?

Comment: It's 3d, and the characters are on a ground plane.

Comment: It's player versus pc, and the angles are only front, back and side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know which direction the characters are facing, you calculate the dot product of those directions. If the characters only move on the ground plane it is pretty staightforward to decide which side are you on. If the dot product is 0 then you face exactly the side of the opponent. Then you check for some interval against zero and decide if you are on the side or not (so that you can attack from the side even if you are not *exactly* on the side). If the dot product is positive then you are behind, if negative you are in front.
Calculate the dot product by multiplying the facing vectors' of the characters components against each other then sum them up, like:

```
vec1 = (a,b,c)
vec2 = (x,y,z)
dot(vec1,vec2) = a*x+b*y+c*z
```